# Solving a modular exponentiation problem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

How do I solve for $y$ in this congruence:

$$11^{112111} \equiv y \bmod 113$$

I saw that $113$ is prime and so by Fermat's Little Theorem, it means $a^{112} \equiv 1 \bmod 113$.

$$11^{112111} \equiv 11^{112 \cdot 1000} 11^{111} \equiv 11^{112^{1000}} 11^{111} \equiv 1^{1000} 11^{111} \equiv 11^{111} \bmod 113$$

Assuming that is correct so far I don't know how to solve $11^{111} \bmod 113$

Comment: If you multiplied through by $11$ you'd get $11^{112} \equiv 1 \equiv y \pmod {113}$

Comment: Not at all useful, but pretty: $11^{10}\equiv 111 \pmod{113}$ :-)

Comment: $y=11^{112111}$ is a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x$ be the number we are after. Then $11x\equiv 11^{112}\equiv 1\pmod{113}$.  So we are looking for the modular inverse of $11$.

Multiply by $11$ and reduce mod $113$. We get $8x\equiv 11\pmod{113}$. This is equivalent to $8x\equiv 124$, which is equivalent to $2x\equiv 31$, which is equivalent to $2x\equiv 144$, which is equivalent to $x\equiv 72\pmod{113}$.

Comment: "Then $11x\equiv 1\pmod{113}$" What?

Comment: @SeanHill: I added an intermediate step.

Comment: "Multiply by $11$ and reduce mod $113$" Why? If you have $11x \equiv 1 \bmod 113$ and multiply both sides by $11$ isn't this $121x \equiv 11\bmod 113$ or $8x \equiv 11 \bmod 113$?

Comment: Why multiply? Because it lets us produce a nice small number. I had (as you pointed out) an error, but same strategy works.